# pandas: split a column on multiple words present in all cells

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, split

I would like to split the column in this dataframe on name into two columns,

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Steve _ (ICANA) Smith', 'Joe _ (ICANA) Nadal',
                       'Roger _ (ICANA) Federer_blu']})
```

My desired output would be:

```
                          Name  First    Last
0        Steve _ (ICANA) Smith  Steve    Smith
1          Joe _ (ICANA) Nadal  Joe      Nadal
2  Roger _ (ICANA) Federer_blu  Roger    Federer_blu
```

so I would like to get rid of ' _ (ICANA)'. using split, I have done,

```
df1[['First','last']] = df1.Name.str.split(r"\b _ (ICANA)\b", expand=True)
```

which returns the following error,

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex was incorrect, you need to escape the parentheses:

```
df1[['First','last']] = df1.Name.str.split(r"\s*_ \(ICANA\)\s*", expand=True)
```

However, to avoid any issue, the best remains to use `extract`, which will ensure a fixed number of output columns:

```
df1[['First','last']] = df1.Name.str.extract(r'(\w*)\s*_ \(ICANA\)\s*(\w*)')
```